# Bootstrap 3 Dynamic image gallery with expanding tiles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following image represented here as a picture

[image: Initial Load]

And the HTML code that paints this.

```
<div id="Gallery1" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery3" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery4" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery5" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery6" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery7" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
<div id="Gallery8" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 gallery-outer">
    <div class="product-tile-inner">...</div>
</div>
```

I have a small button inside each div to make it expand and show more details, but whenever I click on any of the buttons, the following happens.

[image: After expanding]

Also, this is the CSS used for the `gallery-outer` class name.

```
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: top;
```

And this is the `gallery-inner` class name

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
min-height: 430px;
```

Any ideas on a workaround for this? Sorry I don't have a CodePen, I have adapted the code to protect the real one.

Comment: Post the HTML of a *single* tile, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a grid with items that will always have *equal height per row*. It can be done with **Bootstrap 3** and a little more custom CSS:

```js
$('.btn-block').on('click', function() {
  var $block = $(this).closest(".product-tile-inner");
  $block.height("+=30");
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.product-tile-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.product-tile-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-tile-inner .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is the `flex-direction: column`?

Comment: @Mayhem It is not necessary in this particular layout, but just in case your layout is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Bootstrap 4** with **flexbox** to make a grid with items that will always have *equal height per row*:

```js
$('.btn-block').on('click', function() {
  var $block = $(this).closest(".product-tile-inner");
  $block.height("+=30");
});
```

```css
.grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.product-tile-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.product-tile-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-tile-inner .btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: .85;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="product-tile-inner">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600/?gravity=west">
        <div class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Razvan, thanks for the detailed answer here. Although I really appreciate your effort on this, I was expecting an alternative with Bootstrap 3, not 4

Comment: @Mayhem If I change to Bootstrap 3, and get the *same result*, would it be ok?

Comment: That would be ideal, yes